# Función para leer carácter por carácter

Tags: c++

Quisiera saber una función para leer carácter por carácter o línea por línea en un ciclo while en el cual al objeto se le manda como parámetro un archivo txt como string.
Archivo:

```
#include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Estadistica{
private:
  int L;
  int P;
  int C;

public:
  Estadistica(string n);
  int cuantasLineas();
  int cuantasPalabras();
  int cuantosCaracteres();
};

Estadistica::Estadistica(string n){

  ifstream f( string n);
  char c;
  while(f.get(c)) // En esta instrucción me marca un error
    {
      if(c==' ')
        {
              P= P + 1;
     }  
     }    
  f.close();
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido a StackOverflow. Te sugiero eches un vistazo al [tour] para ver un poco cómo funciona este portal. En cualquier caso te sugiero que publiques el código mínimo y a ser posible completo (es decir que sea compilable y ejecutable). Piensa que el que responda no solo te estará ayudando a tí sino a todos los que vengan detrás de ti con la misma pregunta

Comment: ¿Leer la entrada del usuario? ¿Leer un archivo? ¿Leer un puntero en memoria?... ¿Podrías ser un poco más específico?

Comment: Disculpa, leer un archivo   #include<string.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<fstream>
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Estadistica{
private:
  int L;
  int P;
  int C;

public:
  Estadistica(string n);
  int cuantasLineas();
  int cuantasPalabras();
  int cuantosCaracteres();
};

Estadistica::Estadistica(string n){

  ifstream f( string n);
  char c;
  while(f.get(c)) // En esta instruccion me marca un error
    {
      if(c==' ')
  {
     P= P + 1;
  } 
     }    
  f.close();
}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
ifstream f( string n);
```

Esa línea representa la declaración de una función. Lo que quieres es crear un objeto `f` de tipo `ifstream` la sintaxis esperada es:

```
// opcion 1
ifstream f(n);

// opcion 2
ifstream f = ifstream(n);
```

---

Edito:

Salvo que compiles con el estándar C++11 o con alguno más moderno el constructor disponible de `ifstream` no admite un `std::string` comparámetro, como puedes verificar [aquí](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ifstream/ifstream/)

En tal caso tienes varias posibles soluciones:

```
// opcion 1
ifstream f(n.c_str()); // no admite string pero si const char*

// opcion 2
ifstream f;
f.open(n.c_str()); // tampoco admite string
```

Comment: me marca esto: [Error] no matching function for call to 'std::basic_ifstream<char>::basic_ifstream(std::string&)'

Comment: @Ricky1904 revisa la respuesta

Comment: Gracias Amigo, me sirvió bastante

Answer (score 0):

Puedes leer carácter a carácter utilizando iteradores de flujo (*stream*):

```
std::ifstream f("archivo.txt");

using iterador = std::istreambuf_iterator<char>;

for (auto begin = iterador(f), end = iterador(); begin != end; ++begin)
{
    if (*begin == ' ')
    {
        P = P + 1;
    }
}
```

Puedes ver el código funcionando en <kbd>[Wandbox 三へ( へ՞ਊ ՞)へ ﾊｯﾊｯ](https://wandbox.org/permlink/XGws1UBgYAoEc4kM)</kbd>.